# react-chart-2 <"Line" is not a registered controller.>

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

Currently, I am making a code that automatically draws input values into a chart when input is received through react. I'm trying to add a saved chart using usestate for testing, but I can't proceed with the error <"Line" is not a registered controller.>.

Any way to fix this error?

Here's the code:

```
import {CreatChart} from './WidgetCRUD'
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
import {Radar,Line,Pie,Doughnut,PolarArea, Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2' 

const options = 
{
  responsive: true, 
  scales: 
  {
    yAxes: 
    [
      {
        ticks: 
        {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

const data = 
{
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' , '8', '9','10'],
  datasets: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [30, 9, 24, 50,-20,20, 17, 45, 49],
    }
  ],
}


const main = () =>
{
    const [createChart, setCreateChart] = useState([])
    setCreateChart(<Line data = {data} options={options} style={{ position: "relative"}}/>)
    return (
       <div>{createChart}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code so you need to adapt it to yours, first you need to import everything you need from chart.js, depending on what chart you need, I'm using Line Chart

```
import {
Chart as ChartJS,
CategoryScale,
LinearScale,
PointElement,
LineElement,
Title,
Tooltip,
Legend,
TimeScale,
ChartOptions
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

Then you need to register the elements:

```
ChartJS.register(
 CategoryScale,
 LinearScale,
 PointElement,
 LineElement,
 TimeScale,
 Title,
 Tooltip,
 Legend
);
```

For more info check these links:
[Link 1](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/working-with-datasets)
[Link 2](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: thank you answetr, but it didn't work. 
("bar" is not a registered element.), 
("radialLinear" is not a registered scale.) 
(The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ChartComponent)> component:)
like error occurs. how can i fix it?

Comment: @gaviSu You need to add it to ChartJS.register(....);

Comment: still dont working

Comment: @gaviSu Can You provide the code that you're using now

Comment: now it is work. i guess my setting was wrong. thank you ur answer